# How to print only the first 2 digit of a double in C

Tags: c, printf, double

```
for (total = 0; total < amount; total++){
    int flip = rand() % 2;
    if (flip == 1){
        heads++;
    }
    else{
        tails++;
    }
}

//  Percentage calculation
percentage_heads = heads/amount * 100;
percentage_tails = tails/amount * 100;



printf("Tails: %d\nHeads: %d (%.2f percent)", tails, heads, percentage_heads);
```

Whenever variable "percentage_heads" equals 100 it's prints out fine but for anything else (EX: 50.01, 34.87, etc.) it just prints 0.00. How can I get the program to print out the true percentage?

Comment: `heads` and `tails` and `amount` are integer types... eg `999/1000` gives `0`; `1000/1000` gives `1`

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. This includes all variable types and values that reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unrelated: you know `tails` is `total - heads`, no need to keep a count of both outcomes :-)

Comment: What happens with `percentage_heads = 100.0 * heads/amount`?

Answer (score 1):

Here the issue is the below calculation evaluates from left to right based on the `implicit type conversion`.

```
percentage_heads = heads/amount * 100;
     ^               ^     ^       ^ 
   double           int   int     int
```

Above one evaluates as, `heads/amount` to `0` or `1` and multiplied with `100`, results in either `0` or `100` respectively.
So, the solution is by using a `explicit type conversion` or by making one of values in the expression as float or double to make use of **automatic** `implicit type conversion`.

```
// explicit type conversion
percentage_heads = (double) heads/amount * 100;
```

This evaluates considering the expression as double and will provide the result with decimal values.

```
// implicit type conversion
percentage_heads = 100.0 * heads/amount;
      ^             ^        ^     ^
    double         float    int   int
```

When this is evaluated from left to right, `100.0` is hit first and the operation is performed based on it's type i.e., `float` and hence it provides the result with proper decimal values.

**Note:**

```
// thought implicit type conversion would work but not
percentage_heads = heads/amount * 100.0;
     ^               ^     ^       ^
   double           int   int     float
```

Here as the expression is evaluated from left to right, first the `heads/amount` is hit and gets evaluated as `0` or `1` which would still result in the values as `0.0` or `100.0`.